# rails generate command return error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've decided to learn Rails but it keeps on throwing problems at me. I managed to solve them myself but this one just wont go away. I'm following this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)
but when I try to create a new controller with `rails generate controller welcome index` I get this error:

```
    Constantins-MacBook-Pro-2:n00b Constantin$ rails generate controller welcome index
/Users/Constantin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@n00b/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/Constantin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@n00b/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Constantin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@n00b/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Constantin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@n00b/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/Constantin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Constantin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Form what I've found online it means that the compiler is running through my application every time I create new controllers etc. and then finds these errors. Correct? But since I haven't edited a single line of code yet I don't understand where these come from nor what he is trying to tell me. It's probably something else that I missed but I just can't find a solution to it neither online nor from try 'n error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `bundle install` - one of your gem dependencies might be broken seeing you are using 4.1.0.

Comment: gives me the same error again....this looks like a tough one ...

Comment: Also try first deleting your `Gemfile.lock` before running `bundle install` to make it rebuild the gem dependencies.  Nick's edited answer is useful too - help to determine if the problem is with just this app or with all apps in your environment.  Good luck!

Comment: Okay so I deleted the Gemfile.lock from the root directory of my  rails application. Cleared my bin and then ran `bundle install` command but it leads into the exact same errors at the exact same lines etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're in your home directory.  To generate a rails controller you should be in the directory of the rails application you want to modify.

edit: If this isn't the case, paste what happens when you do this (from a clean directory):

```
rails new new-app
cd new-app
rails g controller welcome index
```

Comment: No. Just to make sure I cd into the directory in a new Terminal window and ran the same command again but I get the exact same error...

Comment: Ok, then see my updates.  We have little information to work from here.

Comment: Okay so apparently it works now. It starts creating files and places them in the directories app/... tests/... etc. I guess its working now. Thanks a lot! I still have no idea what happened. Would be interesting to know but oh well.

Comment: No problem, Rails is not a small simple tool, it's really confusing at first keeping your head around where everything lives and how it all goes together.